# Undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass - Static Pages Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I try to add a link in the menu to a simple html page, but when I try to go to the link I get an error as in the title. I'm newbie in Rails and I can't understand this error, I try add one static html page. Where is the problem? Please help.

In menu

```
    <li><%= link_to "test" , pages_test_path %></li>
```

Routes

```
  Test::Application.routes.draw do
  post "inquiry/create"
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  resources :inquiries
  get "pages/test"
  end
```

Pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

Test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Error messages

```
<% if item.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger fade in" id="error_messages">
      <div id="error_explanation">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <% item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div><!--/alert-->
<% else %>
  <div id="error_messages" class="hide"></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems item object is nil. Meaning this is not declared in your controller.

Declare the variable @item in your controller like below.

```
@item = Item.find(your_item_id)
```

or

```
item = Item.new(your_params)
@item = item.save
```

Then change your html like below.

```
<% if @item.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger fade in" id="error_messages">
      <div id="error_explanation">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div><!--/alert-->
<% else %>
  <div id="error_messages" class="hide"></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, further I get this error.

Comment: You were right, I had a problem yet in another place. After solving the main problem, your answer really helped me. Thanks!